# How does Chrome (and other browsers) handle a “setTimeout” set to higher than 1000 milliseconds when a browser tab is hidden and inactive?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, settimeout, setinterval

I’m debugging some login/logout issues on a site maintained by an outside vendor for a client and hopefully the title explains things, but more details are below.

As I understand it, any JavaScript running in a hidden tab in Chrome will alter the value of any `setTimeout` to be 1000 milliseconds to maintain overall system performance and not waste resources. As [explained on this site](https://usefulangle.com/post/280/settimeout-setinterval-on-inactive-tab):

> “Browsers do exactly this. For inactive tabs, they automatically throttle timers to run every 1 second, regardless of the original delay specified in the code. **For example, if the code originally used setInterval() to run some code every 50 ms, once the application is moved to a background tab, the interval automatically becomes 1000 ms (1 second)**.”

That definitely makes sense in the case of a `setTimeout` value that is set lower than 1,000 milliseconds like 50 milliseconds and such. But what about values higher than 1,000 milliseconds?

Will Chrome set the `setTimeout` value to 1,000 milliseconds  even though 900,000 milliseconds (aka: 900 seconds, aka: 15 minutes) is clearly higher than that?

Here is a chunk of code from the vendor’s web page I believe is causing issues I am attempting to assist in debugging. It doesn’t do its job when it is in a hidden tab.

```
function keepSessionAlive() {
    if (externalAdminWindow && externalAdminWindow.closed) {
        externalAdminWindow = null;
    }
    if (externalFGWindow && externalFGWindow.closed) {
        externalFGWindow = null;
    }
    if (externalAdminWindow || externalFGWindow) {
        $find("ctl00_RadAjaxManager1").ajaxRequest("KeepAlive");
        setTimeout(function() {
            keepSessionAlive();
        }, 900000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers **throttle** timeouts in inactive tabs. It means that all `setTimeout`'s will have a minimum of 1000ms timeout. Everything longer than that should work as expected. So, answering your question, 15min timeout should not be affected.

Check out `setTimeout`'s *Timeouts in inactive tabs* section on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#timeouts_in_inactive_tabs